# How can I display account hierarchy from community (customer account portal)?

Tags: community, account, customer-portal, partner, hierarchy

I launch a community with the customer account portal template. The account hierarchy is launched in Salesforce.

But when I switch to the community, I don't see the account hierarchy, and the button "view account hierarchy" isn't displayed.

I log in to the community as system admin and as partner user. I see nothing but the parent account field on the detail page.

How can I do to see the account hierarchy in customer account portal ?

Comment: Unfortunately the account hierarchy function is not available for community users.  You'll need to search AppExchange to see if there's a custom component, or you'll have to build your own.

Comment: Ok, thank you @DavidCheng for your answer.